# How to access an IP in a subnet of another NC card?

Tags: networking, connection, router, tcp, subnet

I searched and could not find an answer for this.. not even a discussion about it...

I need to develop an application to talk to a robot in our shop floor... no big deal about the code... The issue is as follows:

This robot is connected to an industrial PC that is connected to our production network. This industrial PC has two NICs, NIC #1 has TCP/IP settings set to connect to our production network (IP something like 10.9.100.100), and the NIC #2 is configured to have its IP on a subnet address (Something like 192.168.127.10).

The robot has an IP address too, which is in the subnet of the NIC #2 of the industrial PC. The robot´s IP is something like 192.168.127.20

There´s an application running on the industrial PC that keeps polling data from the robot, like its status, cycle time, etc. This application then sends the data collected from the robot to a server in our production network.

Simply put, it´s like grab data via NIC #2 and send it to a server in the production network via NIC #1.

In order to test my application from within the IDE and debug it, I´d like to connect to the robot from my desktop (Which is in the production network (10.9.100.200)...), to that IP in the subnet the robot is, that is, the IP subnet set in the NIC #2 from the industrial PC.

I have access to the industrial PC and I could install Visual Studio on it and code via remote desktop. Then for sure I could access that robot. But that would not be cool...

Is there any way, setting or application that allows me to reach that robot from my production network?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is port forwarding. You can set up the industrial PC to listen on a certain port number x on NIC 1 and forward all connections to the robot's IP address on port number y (where y may be equal to x if port x is not used by another application on the industrial PC, otherwise you set it to a different value).

This would be trivial to set up on most Unixes, but since you're running Windows it's a bit more complicated. If your traffic is TCP, Windows supports port forwarding via [netsh](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731068(v=ws.10).aspx). If your traffic is UDP, you need to use some third-party application. With some Googling I found [this one](http://aluigi.altervista.org/mytoolz.htm)
(look for "Simple UDP proxy/pipe"). Note that I have no experience with this  program and you should be careful when downloading executables from unknown sources; but AFAICT the source code is also provided, so you could compile it yourself if needed.

On [the same page](http://aluigi.altervista.org/mytoolz.htm) you can also find a TCP forwarder if the native Windows one doesn't work for you.